# How to use a variable with a shell script command?

Tags: shell

The following command works well:

```
psql -h localhost -U user dados -f /etc/bkpdb/04-03-2015.sql&
```

However, when I use a variable in it:

```
valor=04-03-2015
psql -h localhost -U user dados -f /etc/bkpdb/$valor.sql&
```

It does not work.

It happens the following error:

```
.sql: No such file or directory2015
```

Comment: Try using `${valor}` instead

Comment: Make `$valor.sql&` `${valor}.sql&`

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error with the commands you've given.

Comment: probably another carriage-return `\r` issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, the problem is that your file is saved on Windows where lines end with `\r\n` instead of Unix `\n`.

You can tell because of the weird, trailing `2015` in the error message. It got there because the tool intended to write out a message like:

```
psql: failed: /etc/bkpdb/04-03-2015\r.sql: No such file or directory
```

But due to the carriage return `\r`, the cursor moves to the start of the column, and starts overwriting the start of the message:

```
p̶s̶q̶l̶:̶ ̶f̶a̶i̶l̶e̶d̶:̶ ̶/̶e̶t̶c̶/̶b̶k̶p̶d̶b̶/̶0̶4̶-̶0̶3̶-2015
.sql: No such file or directory
```

You're therefore left with:

```
.sql: No such file or directory2015
```

To solve this, just convert your file from Windows/DOS format to Unix, either in your text editor or with `dos2unix`, `fromdos` or `tr -d '\r'`. Here's trouble shooting step #1 from the [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info):

1. **Check whether your script or data has DOS style end-of-line characters**

   - Use `cat -v yourfile` or `echo "$yourvariable" | cat -v` .

     DOS carriage returns will show up as `^M` after each line.

     If you find them, delete them using `dos2unix` (a.k.a. `fromdos`) or `tr -d '\r'`

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
valor=04-03-2015
psql -h localhost -U user dados -f /etc/bkpdb/${valor}.sql &
```